# Enabling windows authentication in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, sitefinity

I am on vista home premium (32 bit) and I need to enable windows authentication for IIS because the Sitefinity sample site returns a 401. However, in add windows features, there is no sign of windows authentication despite having expanded all the treeviews.

How can I enable windows auth?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows authentication is a feature that's only available in upper editions such as Business/Ultimate as Tchami pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28WS.10%29.aspx) should answer your question. Also, to install IIS on Vista Home Premium [look here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754752%28WS.10%29.aspx)

But in short:

Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. 
In Features View, double-click Authentication.
On the Authentication page, select Windows Authentication.
In the Actions pane, click Enable to use Windows authentication.

Comment: I did that but don't see Windows Authentication (I see all other types). I can't even install it via Windows Features :(

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it seems it's not available at all in the Home Premium edition (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753198%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Guess you will have to either upgrade or create a virtual machine.